# jsp setting variable not working

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to do something very simple:

```
<c:set var="show-popup" value="true"/>
<span>SHOW POPUP val: ${show-popup} eval: ${show-popup eq 'true'}</span>
```

But this is displayed on the page:

```
SHOW POPUP val: 0 eval: false
```

Am I setting it incorrectly? The statements are next to each other, and I'm not setting it anywhere else on the page.
What did I goof up?

Answer (score 0):

It ...... looks like no one even tested the original code. This fixes it:

```
<c:set var="showPopup" value="true"/>
<span>SHOW POPUP val: ${showPopup}</span>
```

TIL to be careful with var names in jsp.
I think the evaluation including the dash was attempting a subtraction or something?